# Connecting internal APIs

Tags: api, microservices, devops, infrastructure

I am looking for a software that can within defined timeframe request one endpoint in the system and provide its output to another one. I am dealing with internal endpoints, that is why 3rd party SaaS are not an option.

Things that I need it to do is

- It should be configurable on the run (preferably through HTTP API)
- It should request one endpoint and feed the output to another one
- It should let to configure time frame
- It should accept various authentication methods (for both sides)
- Preferably support by community and opensource
- Preferably free to use

I made quite extensive research on the internet withing last two days but was able to find only SaaS that provides that. I also asked my collegues at work but they could not suggest me anything useful. I am sure there is already something exists, it just me who could not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for me and looking for various DevOps tools, I discovered that such class of software is refereed as job Schedulers or Workload Automation. Most of the solutions are rather complex commercial system that provides not only such functionality. However there are some open source solutions available as well.

List of available software (it is not complete):

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software